# Is it natural or the way that the numerical system was invented that these magics with numbers exist in Nature?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Why do these exhilarating magics with numbers exist in Nature? Is it natural or are they tricks of numbers the way they were invented or explored?

Classical Fibonacci Sequence = $0, 1, 0+1=1, 1+1=2, 2+1=3...$

Golden Ratio:

$\varphi ^{-1}=[0;1,1,1,\dots ]=0+{\cfrac {1}{1+{\cfrac {1}{1+{\cfrac {1}{1+\ddots }}}}}}$

$10 \times 3 = 30, 10 \times 7 = 70, 10 \times 88 = 880$ just a zero after the number.

$11 \times 7 = 77, 11 \times 9 = 99, 11 \times 11 = 100 + (10 \times (1+1)) + 1 = 121$ when multiplying 57 with 11 the leftmost and rightmost digits will be consecutively 5 and 7 and middle will be the 2 of (5+7) = 12 and 1 will be carried over to left most digit. So the result will be 627

Golden Ratio and Fibonacci Sequence Connection:

A    B     B / A, 2     3       1.5,     3     5       1.666666666..., 5
8       1.6, 8     13      1.625, 13    21      1.615384615..., ...   ...
... 144   233     1.618055556..., 233   377     1.618025751..., ...
...     ...,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers (and all of mathematics) were invented to describe the world around us. No wonder they crop up all over the place.

Sure, people did follow them and their relations way, *way* beyond anything "natural" (Cantor's transfinite numbers have no relation to the real wold!).

Comment: I don't know, I don't think we can explain away "the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics" so easily.